# Friends list and unread messages SQL query giving unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have all day trying to get a result of a SQL query but does not give me the expected result.

My tables at which I consult are:

**tcc_friends**

```
id(PK AUTO_INCREMENT)
user_from (FK tcc_user (nickname) )
user_to (FK tcc_user (nickname) )
```

**tcc_messages**

```
id (PK AUTO_INCREMENT)
message
reg_time
wasRead
id_room (FK tcc_friends(id))
```

test records that have currently inserted are:

**tcc_friends**

```
id_room    user_from    user_to
5             hu        example@gmail.com
6             hu        example222222@hotmail.com
```

**tcc_messages**

```
id          message      id_room
1           a            5
2           b            5
3           c            3
```

**SQL:**

```
select
    u.*,
    f.id_room,COUNT(m.id) as newMessages
from
    tcc_friends f,
    tcc_user u,
    tcc_messages m
where
    u.nickname = 'hu' IN (u.nickname = f.user_from and f.user_to='hu') or
    (u.nickname = f.user_to and f.user_from='hu') AND
    (m.id_room = f.id_room and m.wasRead = 0)
GROUP BY
    u.nickname;
```

**RESULT:**

```
id   nickname                id_room    newMessages
81   example@gmail.com       5          2
```

I'm trying to get a user's friends and also add unread messages but displays only friends who have a message and I'd like to show all friends whether or not unread

Can anybody help me? Regards and Thank you all

Comment: Is it "id" or "id_room" in tcc_friends?  You have two different things.

Comment: fix your joins.. use left joins and you might get a lot closer

Comment: Your `join` conditions are really hard to follow.  You should really be using explicit ``join` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `SELECT *`. It's a horrible practice and you should get out of the habit of doing it as quickly as possible.

Second, learn how to use explicit `JOIN`s. Don't list all of your tables in the `WHERE` clause. That's syntax that has been obsolete (for good reason) for 20 years. That's also what's causing your problem here because all of your joins are `INNER JOIN`s by default.

Try something like this instead:

```
SELECT
    U.id,
    U.nickname,
    F.id_room,
    COUNT(M.id) as newMessages
FROM
    tcc_Friends F
INNER JOIN tcc_User U ON U.nickname = F.user_from
LEFT OUTER JOIN tcc_Messages M ON
    M.id_room = F.id_room AND
    M.wasRead = 0  -- Are you using camelcase or underscores in column names?? Make up your mind and stick to it.
WHERE
    F.user_to = 'hu'
GROUP BY
    U.nickname;
```

That isn't going to get you all the way there, because I'm unclear on what exactly you're trying to get as far as number of unread messages - is it unread messages for the user at all? How does example@gmail.com have 2?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `and m.wasRead = 0` from `m.id_room = f.id_room and m.wasRead = 0` in the `WHERE` clause. By this query you get friends only with messages that have wasRead property 0. By doing above change you will get all the friends and 0 as the count if they don't have any new messages.